# MS-Office add-in SSO - use WebApplicationInfo manifest for Outlook

Tags: outlook, single-sign-on, outlook-addin

I have followed this guide for having SSO in a PowerPoint add-in:

https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

Everything works fine. Now I want to do the excact same with an Outlook add-in. According to the above article it should be possible. Only the Outlook add-in requires the WebApplicationInfo element in VersionOverridesV1_1 section.

I have tried multiple different manifest configurations, but simply cannot get Outlook (desktop version 1708) to accept a manifest with the WebApplicationInfo element.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? - or is this not supported in Outlook yet (despite the comment in the article above).

Best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

follow up this answer..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50729561/4431245

```xml
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
   <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
     ...
     <WebApplicationInfo>
        ...
     </WebApplicationInfo>
   </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
```

as so..
worked for me